# Algo to calculate real trade volume from last 24h volume

Tags: algorithms

Is mostly algo query. I use php. I use a local btc exchange and its API only publishes last 24h volume which changes every few minutes. I have logged this for past week.

I want to try to use it to derive into near real-time volume.
Is it possible to have such an algo?

Example:

Suppose i want to derive real volume from exposed volume. The Exposed volume is only the sum of last 5 trades.

I have tried by one algo like

`current_volume = volume[current_index] - volume[current_index-5]`

`Real Volume:      1  5  8  4  3  1  7  0  3  2  0  6`

`Exposed Volume:              21 21 23 15 14 13 12 11`

`My Algo:                      6  4  0 -7 -7 -8 -11 -4`

But my algo is not giving results that even resemble the real volume.

Comment: Info changes every few mins. there is lot of info.

Comment: You are not giving us enough information.

Comment: I can only guess what you are asking.    Exactly what information do you receive?  Each time you receive the volume, is it the average over all the data for the previous 24 hours, or for yesterday?  What do you mean by "near real-time volume"?  Do mean that you want to know the volume in the last 5 minutes, and you want it now?  Or do you want to know 5-minute averages of the volume, but it's OK to learn that only a day later?

Comment: added more info

Comment: So does that mean that it's OK to learn the 5-minute averages only 24 hours later?  Or, in your example, it's OK to learn the real volume only after a delay of 5 observations?

Comment: I just used 5 min example so we could observe it in smaller scale.

Answer (score 1):

No. The problem is that the change in 24 hour trade volume (over, let's say, 5 minutes) corresponds to the volume in the last 5 minutes, *minus* the trade volume in the same 5 minutes in the previous day. So if you see the trade volume increase by 10 BTC, this tells you that in the past 5 minutes, we traded 10 more BTC than in the same 5 minutes yesterday. But that doesn't tell you whether the trade volume was 20 (and yesterday's volume 10) or 10000 (and yesterday's volume 9990). Of course, you know the total volume, but, in general, there's no way to know how the total volume is distributed over the time of day.

There is can be practically infinite set of possibilities that explain your observations. Barring some very special cases (for instance, the volume traded going to 0 for an entire day) you won't be able to infer anything.

Comment: Well said.  Another very special case: the volume goes down to a local minimum of $k$, and in the 24 hours before that minimum, there are only $k$ times where the volume increased.